# MySQL COUNT(*) from related "visits" table

Tags: mysql

I've been working through a MySQL query and am wondering if there is a better way to do this (without correlated subqueries, etc...). The query in question is

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_visits FROM visit WHERE data_type='gallery'
    and gallery.id=visit.object_id) as num_visits, gallery.id
FROM gallery
    ORDER BY num_visits desc
```

The relavant parts of the table structure are

```
gallery
-------
id

visit
-----
id
data_type --> enum('gallery','etc')
object_id --> ties to various tables
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   SELECT COUNT(v.object_id) as num_visits, g.id
     FROM gallery g
LEFT JOIN visit v ON g.id=v.object_id AND v.data_type='gallery'
 GROUP BY g.id
 ORDER BY num_visits DESC
```

But the better solution (from performance perspective) would be to have the amount of visits precalculated and stored right in `gallery` table (or in some other)

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I needed. I did think of pre-computing results, but am am weary of having redundant data in a large number of tables (the visit table's data_type attribute ties it to several other tables). Thanks a lot for the help.