Get count from table with foreign key
This is a sample table and sample data only. I have three tables:
CREATE TABLE EMP_TBL
(
    EMP_ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE BRANCH_TBL
(
    BRANCH_ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    BRANCH_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (BRANCH_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE EMP_BRANCH_TBL
(
    EMP_BRANCH_ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    EMP_ID INT NOT NULL,
    BRANCH_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EMP_BRANCH_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMP_TBL(EMP_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (BRANCH_ID) REFERENCES BRANCH_TBL(BRANCH_ID)    
)


INSERT INTO EMP_TBL (EMP_NAME) VALUES ('MNOP');
INSERT INTO EMP_TBL (EMP_NAME) VALUES ('ABCD');

INSERT INTO BRANCH_TBL (BRANCH_NAME) VALUES ('SALES');
INSERT INTO BRANCH_TBL (BRANCH_NAME) VALUES ('LOAN');
INSERT INTO BRANCH_TBL (BRANCH_NAME) VALUES ('HR');

INSERT INTO EMP_BRANCH_TBL (EMP_ID, BRANCH_ID) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO EMP_BRANCH_TBL (EMP_ID, BRANCH_ID) VALUES (2, 3);

I want count of employee in different branch. How can I do that?
branch_name   count
-------------------
SALES           0
LOAN            1
HR              1


You probably need a LEFT JOIN and a GROUP BY.  This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10922848/20418616

MySQL or Oracle? They're not the same. MySQL doesn't have IDENTITY.

You can do this by using a LEFT JOIN between the BRANCH_TBL and EMP_BRANCH_TBL tables, then using the COUNT function with GROUP BY to count the number of employees in each branch.
SELECT b.branch_name, COUNT(Eb.EMP_id) AS count
  FROM branch_tbl b
  LEFT JOIN emp_branch_tbl eb
    ON b.branch_id = eb.branch_id
 GROUP BY b.branch_name
 ORDER BY b.branch_name;


Try with this:
SELECT BRANCH_NAME, count(EMP_TBL.EMP_ID) from BRANCH_TBL 
    left join EMP_BRANCH_TBL on EMP_BRANCH_TBL.BRANCH_ID = BRANCH_TBL.BRANCH_ID 
    left join EMP_TBL on EMP_TBL.EMP_ID = EMP_BRANCH_TBL.EMP_ID 
    GROUP BY BRANCH_TBL.BRANCH_NAME;


This can be done using the GROUP BY and JOIN clauses.
SELECT branch_name, COUNT(emp_tbl.emp_id) 
FROM emp_tbl JOIN emp_branch_tbl ON emp_tbl.emp_id=emp_branch_tbl.emp_id 
JOIN branch_tbl ON emp_branch_tbl.branch_id=branch_tbl.branch_id
GROUP BY branch_name;

First join the tables based on the foreign key references.
Then group the data by the branch name.
Then count how many employees are in each grouped branch.
